# JSDoc compatibility inside jQuery(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana, jsdoc

I have some functions declared inside `jQuery(document).ready(function {})` and I've written JSDoc comments to them. The problem is, they cannot be displayed as tooltips when I focus on function call line. Not essential, however, maybe there is a solution for this? I am using Aptana IDE. I've searched their documentation and googled as well, but didn't find the answer.

Comment: Thx for your answer. My code is correct, I just misspelled it here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Aptana supports ScriptDoc, not JSDoc.

http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/About_Code_Assist#Adding_your_own_code_to_Code_Assist